# MD5 Checksums on Downloads

Tags: security, hash, md5

Why do sites provide MD5 checksums on file downloads? For example, XAMPP at https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html.

My understanding is that it is to show authenticity and credibility, but if that were the case couldn't the site calculate and provide a checksum of whatever file (malicious or not) that they are delivering to you?

Comment: More appropriate on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true that if the site that is hosting the file is compromised, these hashes would provide little value - **but** it is common for there to be a third-party host (to save bandwidth, or provide backup sources). So, if I provide a hash for the file on my site, but I use a third-party host, you could double-check the value to ensure that the file is not being modified by the file host.

In your case, the installer is actually being provided by `sourceforge.net` (at least when I tried it), which, ironically, has been [getting a lot of flack recently](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/05/sourceforge-grabs-gimp-for-windows-account-wraps-installer-in-bundle-pushing-adware/) for modifying files just like we described. So, double checking the hash is probably a good idea!

Another benefit to sites provide these is because a MitM attack could modify files (like executables) in transit. This means that even though you trust the site and the host, there may be some intermediate vulnerability that is infecting the file. Sure, a sufficiently advanced attack could manipulate both, but if that's the case, they probably don't need to go to that trouble.

So, the hash isn't a way of saying that the file is safe. It's a way for you to see if the host providing the file is providing the same file. If you don't trust the web page, then the hash is of no value (security-wise).

---

You didn't ask this, but one reason for providing both and MD5 and SHA1 hash is that while it may be possible [to create a file with an MD5 collision](http://natmchugh.blogspot.com/2015/02/create-your-own-md5-collisions.html), and in some cases [SHA-1 can be broken too](https://malicioussha1.github.io/), I haven't heard of any cases where you can generate a malicious file that is a collision for both. It's trivial for the site to calculate multiple hashes, but computationally unfeasible for an attacker to create a malicious file that "double" collides with the real file (as far as I know!).

Comment: This is awesome -- thanks for such a comprehensive answer. Just to clarify a few things.

1) The third-party host would only be responsible for the download of the target file itself, while the original site itself would host the hash (either MD5 or SHA1). Like you said, this is assuming you trust the host of the hash not to have modified the file since they could easily just generate a new hash, correct? Therefore, as long as they are trusted, the only (reasonable) way the third-party could provide a false file is if the two were working together. Correct?

Comment: working together, or if a malicious user compromised both systems. In fact, if they compromised the web server, they could just point to a different host and produce a valid hash. You have to trust the website either way, but if they include the hash you don't have to ALSO trust the file host. It's for proving that something is wrong, not necessarily proving that everything is safe.

Comment: Really great answer. Thanks @Gray

Answer (score 1):

Hash functions such as MD5 validate the integrity of a file. Authenticity verification is provided when you compare the hash value with one received from an authenticated source, which in this example is the XAMPP website. A hash function can be run against any file or data stream, so yes, a site can calculate and provide a checksum of **any** file, malicious or not.